# How to get a JSON unique field's name and deeply nested child field's value in Golang?

Tags: json, parsing, go

I have a json file that looks like this

```
{
  "links": {
    "uniqueurl_1": {
      "a": {
        "b": [
          "stuff"
        ],
        "I": {
          "want": {
            "to": "morestuff",
            "go": {
              "in": {
                "here": {
                  "and": "array",
                  "itis": {
                    "very": "string",
                    "deep": "stringIwant"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And I want to get the `uniqueurl_1` (that is always different for each link), and I also want to get the "deep" field's value ("stringIwant")

I know if it's not too deeply nested, you can just create a bunch of structs in Golang, but when it's this deep would it still be the only/best way to do it?

Comment: you can unmarshal any nested json by creating nested struct. The only thing is dynamic value of `uniqueurl_1`, for that you can create interface{}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your JSON is missing opening brace.
Have a try in this way:

```
{
  "links": {
    "uniqueurl_1": {
      "a": {
        "b": [
          "stuff"
        ],
        "I": {
          "want": {
            "to": "morestuff",
            "go": {
              "in": {
                "here": {
                  "and": "array",
                  "itis": {
                    "very": "string",
                    "deep": "stringIwant"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And use the following code to access you data:

```
package main

import "encoding/json"

func UnmarshalNotSoDeep(data []byte) (NotSoDeep, error) {
    var r NotSoDeep
    err := json.Unmarshal(data, &r)
    return r, err
}

func (r *NotSoDeep) Marshal() ([]byte, error) {
    return json.Marshal(r)
}

type NotSoDeep struct {
    Links Links `json:"links"`
}

type Links struct {
    Uniqueurl1 Uniqueurl1 `json:"uniqueurl_1"`
}

type Uniqueurl1 struct {
    A A `json:"a"`
}

type A struct {
    B []string `json:"b"`
    I I        `json:"I"`
}

type I struct {
    Want Want `json:"want"`
}

type Want struct {
    To string `json:"to"`
    Go Go     `json:"go"`
}

type Go struct {
    In In `json:"in"`
}

type In struct {
    Here Here `json:"here"`
}

type Here struct {
    And  string `json:"and"` 
    Itis Itis   `json:"itis"`
}

type Itis struct {
    Very string `json:"very"`
    Deep string `json:"deep"`
}
```

Comment: so basically the "create a legion of structs" type of thing? Kinda not Golang related but would a different language say python be better at constructing this thing? (Json->Json (modified))

Comment: Both solutions, Golang and Python, are long, at first look Go is more readable. Choose the one you prefer.

Comment: Hi, it looks like this solution can deeply go into my structure, but the issue is each of my links are unique. Say I have another "uniqueurl_2" (not named 1, 2, 3... of course), then when I run the code I won't get uniqueurl_2. Does this mean I'd have to make a separate struct to contain each and every "uniqueurl_N" field?

Comment: Well, you can implement an array of links, replace the `Links` struct as follow: `type Links struct {
    Uniqueurl1 []Uniqueurl1 `json:"uniqueurl_1"`
}`

Comment: Won't I have an array of Uniqueurl1's though, and I want to have a Uniqueurl1, 2, 3, etc. The Links struct you provided contains an array of objects all of type Uniqueurl1 right?

Comment: Yes, it is. If it's not so much trouble you can change `Uniqueurl1` in `Uniqueurl` and add an index field (where to put 1,2...N) to the struct other than A.

Answer (score 2):

For this case you can use [gojsonq - A simple Go package to Query over JSON Data](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq) library.
Here is [full list of available queries](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq/wiki/Queries#selectproperties).

So if you want get the value (`stringIwant`), you can choose or method [From](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq/wiki/Queries#frompath) or method [Find](https://github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq/wiki/Queries#findpath).

Example below:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/thedevsaddam/gojsonq"
)

const json = `{
  "links": {
    "uniqueurl_1": {
      "a": {
        "b": [
          "stuff"
        ],
        "I": {
          "want": {
            "to": "morestuff",
            "go": {
              "in": {
                "here": {
                  "and": "array",
                  "itis": {
                    "very": "string",
                    "deep": "stringIwant"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}`

func main() {
    key := "uniqueurl_1"
    query := "links." + key + ".a.I.want.go.in.here.itis.deep"
    fmt.Println(gojsonq.New().JSONString(json).From(query).Get())
    fmt.Println(gojsonq.New().JSONString(json).Find(query).(string))
}
```

Output:

> stringIwant
>
> stringIwant